#  FrameView with "flip" animation images not scaling down

Tags: android, image, layout, resize, scaling

Can't seem to work out what I've got wrong...

I've got a card game I'm building with a flipping turn over card and some text views below that display information.

I have the following main.xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="6" >

        <include
            android:id="@+id/frameview1"
            layout="@layout/first_card" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/frameview2"
            layout="@layout/second_card" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_mainMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:text="@string/resetMessage"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_subMessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="2.5"
        android:minLines="3"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_cardsRemainingLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:text="@string/cardsRemainingLabel"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_cardsRemaining"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/text_cardsRemainingLabel"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text_cardsRemainingLabel"
            android:text="@string/cardsRemainingInitial"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_kings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/text_cardsRemainingLabel"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:text="@string/kingsInitial"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_kingsLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/text_cardsRemainingLabel"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/text_kings"
            android:text="@string/kingsLabel"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I also have the following two XML files that hold the card images for "pre" and "post" flip within the FrameView as per http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_card"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:background="@drawable/empty"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cardImageDesc"
        android:src="@drawable/card_back_rof" />

</LinearLayout>
```

(The first_card.xm land second_card.xml are identical save for the id value)

Now for the problem:
The image files I am using are about 350 pixels tall and despite using the `layout_weight` on my main `LinearLayout` this is not scaling down to fit on my screen.

I've tried using `maxHeight` values in every place I can think of it, but that hasn't worked, and besides - I don't want to put hard coded pixel limits into the view when I feel like it should all resize itself automatically.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Mark